# How to update second tab if first tab insert data in local database in react native?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, tabs, insert-update, react-native-flatlist

I am using two tabs in my project. In first tab there is a code for insert data in `sqlite` local database. Second tab is for list data. while I am on second tab insert data perform by first tab. So, I want to update my second tab flat list automatically. Please Help me for that. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using redux. just dispatch an action in the tab where you insert data. this action will update your store state and therefore your second tab will get updated props from the store state. you need to learn how to use redux if you are not using it already.

Comment: I am not using redux. redux will update second tab automatically if I insert data in local database from first tab? . Thanks for answering.. :)

Comment: Yes. You have the option to accept my answer if you think it is worth it.

Comment: I know that. I will sure accept your answer and vote after redux working fine with my case or related to it. Thank you .